# Don't work change background color contentView in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

```
if indexPath.row == 2 {
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 237/255, green: 237/255, blue: 237/255, alpha: 1)
} else{ 
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
}
```

Not working on `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `willDisplayCellsAtIndexPath` methods.

Comment: What do you have in cell.contentView?

Comment: Do you have another view which covers full content view ?

Comment: add some additional code

Comment: Check your UITableViewDelegate connections

Answer (score 1):

if you want to change background color of cell use `cell.backgroundColor`.

but if you still want to use `contentView.backgroundColor` make sure to provide `float` values to Red, Green and Blue. just replace `cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 237/255, green: 237/255, blue: 237/255, alpha: 1)` with `cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 237/255.0, green: 237/255.0, blue: 237/255.0, alpha: 1)`

Answer (score 0):

If you're having other view on content view of cell then content view background will not show in any case.